# Convert DOM to native HTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, form-data

I need to send some HTML to a service that converts HTML to PDF. the service accepts a payload that is form-data (a file).

how can I take some of the HTML from the DOM, and convert it into a file, which I can use in my payload ?

```
<p>some other HTML</p>
    <div id="content">
      some content
    </div>

    const html = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;

    const builder = new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'});
```

I get this error
**The format of the request must be of multipart/form-data type.**

Comment: You can get html with `document.body.innerHTML` and then create blob from it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: I think you are right with the blob. Could you give an example ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Sending_binary_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got it working here is the solution - NOTE This is an Angular 8 solution, but vanilla javascript is pretty close**

```
const formData = new FormData();
const html = this.myInput.nativeElement.innerHTML;
const htmlWithDoc = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>Document</title></head><body>' + style + html + '</body></html>';

formData.append('blob', new Blob([htmlWithDoc], {type: 'text/html'}));

this._dataService.htmlToPdf(formData).subscribe(response => {
  this.saveToFileSystem(response);
});

private saveToFileSystem(response) {
 const filename = 'test'; // parts[1].split('=')[1];
 const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
 saveAs(blob, filename);
}

htmlToPdf(payload) {
    const location = 'my API';
    return this._http.post(
      location,
      payload,
      {responseType: 'blob'}
      ).pipe(res => res);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change css style on your own.

```js
      function downloadPDF(){
            var printContents = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
            var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
        }
    
        function redirect() {
            window.location.href = "/user-landing-page";
    
        }
```

```html
    <html class="gr__cuetmwa_org"><head><title>Membership Form|Engr. Anik Islam | 400400505 </title>
    
        <style>
            @media  print {
                #freespace {page-break-after: always;}
            }
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background-color: #FAFAFA;
                font: 11pt "Tahoma";
            }
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .page {
                width: 21cm;
                min-height: 29.7cm;
                padding: .2cm;
                margin: .001cm auto;
                border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
                background: transparent;
                /*box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);*/
            }
            .uploaded-image{
                display:block;
                height: 37mm;
                width: 37mm;
                float: right;
            }
            .uploaded-image-sign{
                display:block;
                height: 57px;
                width: 263px;
                float: right;
            }
            .no-padding{
                padding: 0;
            }
            .px-padding{
                padding: 5px;
             }
            .border {
                border: 1px solid #0000ff;
            }
            .border-right{
            border-right: 1px solid #0000ff ;
            }
            .border-bottom{
                border-bottom: 1px solid #0000ff
            }
            .border-top {
                border-top: 1px solid #0000ff
            }
            .border-top{
                border-top: 1px solid #0000ff;
            }
            .thumbnail{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            .header-logo{
               width: 492px;
            }
            .intermidiate-gap{
                border-right:  1px solid #0000ff;
            }
            .cell-info{
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .text-right{
                text-align: right;
            }
            .text-left{
                text-align: left;
            }
            .text-center{
                text-align: center;
            }
            .title{
                background: #a0a0a0;
            }
            .float-right{
                float: right;
            }
            .float-left{
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.cuetmwa.org/extraassets/libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script rel="text/javascript" src="http://www.cuetmwa.org/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.cuetmwa.org/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="text-align:center;padding: 10px 0 10px 0"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="downloadPDF();" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Click To Download </a></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="text-align:center;padding: 10px 0 10px 0"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="redirect()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Back To Main Page </a></div>
    
    </div>
    <div class="page" id="content">
       <table width="100%" style="text-align: center">
            <tbody><tr class="no-padding">
                <td><img class="header-logo" src="../../../images/form_logo.jpg"></td>
                <td><div class="image-holder">
                        <img class="uploaded-image thumbnail" src="members/images/1536502878.jpg">
                    </div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        <table id="data-table" class="border" width="100%">
           <tbody><tr width="100%">
                <td width="50%"><table width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr><td class="px-padding border-right text-left border-bottom">Genre of Member:</td><td class="px-padding text-right border-bottom">Engineer</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="px-padding border-right text-left border-bottom">Membership Type:</td><td class="px-padding text-right border-bottom">Lifetime</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="px-padding border-right text-left">Member No:</td><td class="px-padding text-right"> 400400505 </td></tr>
                    </tbody></table>
    
    
                </td>
                <td class="intermidiate-gap"></td>
                <td width="50%">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr><td class="px-padding border-right text-left border-bottom">Name:</td><td class="px-padding text-right border-bottom">Engr. Anik Islam</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="px-padding border-right text-left border-bottom">Email:</td><td class="px-padding text-right border-bottom">anik587@gmail.com</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="px-padding border-right text-left ">Mobile:</td><td class="px-padding text-right">01717782151</td></tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="title border-bottom  border-top px-padding">Personal Information</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-left border-right border-bottom">Blood Group:</td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-right border-bottom">A+</td>
                            <td class="intermidiate-gap"></td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-left border-right border-bottom">Birthday:</td>
                            <td class="cell-info text-right border-bottom">1992-11-13</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-left border-right border-bottom">Father's Name:</td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-right border-bottom">Hamidullah Feroz  (Alive) </td>
                            <td class="intermidiate-gap"></td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-left border-right border-bottom">Mother's Name</td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-right border-bottom">Shanaz Parvin  (Alive) </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="cell-info text-left border-right">Spouse's Name</td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-right"> Fabiha Afrida </td>
                            <td class="intermidiate-gap"></td>
                            <td class="cell-info text-left border-right">Childerns:</td>
                            <td class="cell-info text-right">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody><tr><td class="border-bottom"> 1) N/A </td></tr>
                                    <tr><td> 2) N/A </td></tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="title border-bottom  border-top px-padding">Eduational/Professional Information</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-left border-right border-bottom">Student ID:</td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-right border-bottom"> 0904015 </td>
                            <td class="intermidiate-gap"></td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-left border-right border-bottom">Department:</td>
                            <td class="cell-info text-right border-bottom">Computer Science &amp; Engineering</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-left border-right border-bottom">Session:</td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-right border-bottom">2009-2010 (Batch No:40)</td>
                            <td class="intermidiate-gap"></td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-left border-right border-bottom">Passing Year:</td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-right border-bottom">2016</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="cell-info text-left border-right">Organisation:</td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-right ">SSD-Tech</td>
                            <td class="intermidiate-gap"></td>
                            <td class="cell-info text-left border-right">Designation:</td>
                            <td class="cell-info text-right">Engineer</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="title border-bottom  border-top px-padding">Contact Information</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-left border-right border-bottom">Emergency Contact Person:</td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-right border-bottom">Hamidullah Feroz</td>
                            <td class="intermidiate-gap"></td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-left border-right border-bottom">Emergency Contact Person Mobile</td>
                            <td class="cell-info text-right border-bottom">01716201641</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-left border-right">Present Address</td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-right">Cha 92/b, Gupipara , Uttar Badda, Dhaka</td>
                            <td class="intermidiate-gap"></td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-left border-right ">Parmanent Address</td>
                            <td class="cell-info  text-right ">Cha 92/b, Gupipara , Uttar Badda, Dhaka</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="title border-bottom  border-top px-padding">Declaration</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="border-bottom px-padding text-left">I declared that the information I have appended herewith and documents enclosed are complete and correct. If enrolled,
                    I shall conformed to the Rules &amp; Regulations of CUET MEDICAL WELFARE ASSOCIATION and the code of ethics.*</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:25px 0 0 0px"><p class="text-center">2018-09-09 20:21:18</p><p class="text-center border-top">Date</p></td>
                <td colspan="2" class="px-padding text-center"><img class="text-center uploaded-image-sign thumbnail" src="members/signs/1536502878.jpg">
                    <p class="border-top" style="margin-top:60px">Signature</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
    <div id="freespace"></div>
    
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

    </body><span class="gr__tooltip"><span class="gr__tooltip-content"></span><i class="gr__tooltip-logo"></i><span class="gr__triangle"></span></span></html>
```

Comment: not quite what I want.
I want to convert the content with the ID "content" into a file.

I believe i have to use some blob

Comment: It's not clear what do you want?? Do you want to convert HTML into PDF??

Comment: so you want to convert your HTML into text then convert into something else right? And the error you are receiving that is due to your type. Blob is for  images, audio or other multimedia objects, I really can't understand why would you use blob if you just need to convert them into pdf

Comment: I have added the solution